# how to find particular rows or columns in R with specific conditions

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, find, row

For example, if we have a matrix or say array with the following format

```
M = matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1), # the data elements 
    nrow=4,              # number of rows 
    ncol=4,              # number of columns 
    byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows
```

How can find the index of which rows and columns only have 0 inside?
what if we have a more complicated matrix in which we need to find out in the rows or columns with all the numbers inside are in a specific interval?

```
M = matrix(c(1,1,12,34,0,19,15,1,0,17,12,0,21,1,11,1), # the data elements 
    nrow=4,              # number of rows 
    ncol=4,              # number of columns 
    byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows
```

How should I find the column in which all the numbers are between (10 - 20)?

Thank you very much for any one who can help on this.

And, also, I can not use for or while loops to deal with it.

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data. It is very hard to help you in such a way, without data to play with.

Comment: like an array    array_test=array(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1),dim=c(4,4))

Comment: I need to find the columns or rows that only have 0 inside, in an matrix or array like this

Comment: wow. @Zephyr Lian, you reject my helpful edit to create a data set, `M`, then paste my code in yourself, 2x. cheers.

Comment: lol, m sorry if i did something bad, I am a new here. what I did by the way?

Comment: I even did not know how to keep the code as it should seems like before...lol... really sorry if I did something bad...lol

Comment: oh, man, I am not sure but maybe it was because I edited my question? what you said make me feel bad...   really sorry for that and thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
 which(apply(M, 1, sum) == 0 )
[1] 3
 which(apply(M, 2, sum) == 0 )
[1] 3
```

Where with `1` you search for the rows and with `2` columns. The results tell you what row and column has all zeros. With the `M` you can see that the row number 3 and the column number 3 have only zeros.

Or as suggested by Akrun you can use `rowSums` and `colSums` that should be faster.

```
 which(rowSums(M) == 0)
[1] 3
 which(colSums(M) == 0)
[1] 3
```

Comment: you guys are so good. I updated the question, can I do something alike to also figure out the more complicated one?

Comment: @ZephyrLian that sounds like a complete different question. You should ask it at the beginning or open another question because the answer is a little bit more complicated that this one.

Comment: ZephyrLian, break up your questions into distinct parts and post as separate questions and you will help yourself, the people that answer, and people who come here to find answers. @SabDeM is quite correct.